# How do I copy video strip properties?

Tags: workflow, video-sequence-editor

I'm editing a video made with several movie strips. I've changed the properties of one of the strips, like the blend mode, the opacity, the saturation, etc.

I want to copy those properties to the rest of the movie strips, is it possible? Or do I have to modify every strip manually?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just do it by

1. Selecting all strips.
2. Changing value in the active one.
3. Do a right click with mouse cursor over changed value.
4. Choose Copy to Selected item in Pop up menu.

Answer (score 8):

There is an addon called 'Property Chart', you can display a listing of all selected objects properties as well as copy the first property to all others.
This isn't ideal but it at least saves doing it manually.

*@user188's answer is better but keeping mine since its still useful at times since you can see all properties at once.*