# Video Sequence Editor: Is it possible to specify default strip properties?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I use the VSE produce sermon footage involving usually about 50 slides, which use mostly the same properties. Is there a way to specify default values for Blend Mode, Image Offset, and Length so I don't have to manually change them 50 times? I've found [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/437/34997) as a work around, but then I have to add all the slides at the beginning, and I don't always know where they go until I get to them.

Comment: You could add your Images and set them with your desired default values via a neat little python script...

Comment: Do you know of an example of such a script, or are you recommending that I do some studying and make one?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41747/2843 (there are lots of default settings for strips and their automated placement in a new Blend file via python)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this old question went up on Twitter, but if anyone comes by, there is an add-on by Snuq(not me) to handle all the needs when creating a slideshow. Get it here: https://github.com/snuq/SnuSlideshowGenerator/blob/master/Readme.md